# Is the co-domain of Murmur Hash evenly distributed and all-encompassing?

Tags: murmurhash

Consider the version of Murmur Hash (v3) which returns a 32-bit unsigned integer.  Can one assume the co-domain of this function to be evenly distributed between 0 and UINT32_MAX, and to encompass these two values?  I'm looking to generate a pseudo-random double between 0.0 and 1.0 (inclusive) derived from Murmur Hash, as illustrated by the code below:

```
uint32_t hash = MurmurHash3_x86_32 (key, len, seed);
double frac = ((double) hash) / ((double) UINT32_MAX);
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what a *co-domain* is, but i'll answer your question this way:

> Yes, Murmur is good

[**Reference**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed)